# How do I debug production push notifications using Xcode?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I would like to be able to debug handling of push notifications that originate from the production environment using Xcode.  However, it appears that only distribution provisioning profiles can be used with an aps-environment entitlement value of "production".  Is there a way to debug production messages on the device using Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the development push certificates for this. Send your push notifications to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 rather than ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Refer to Apple Documentation for more info.